# Approximating discrete things with continuous ones

Tags: probability, soft-question, approximation, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem

What are some general tips/tricks for, in practice, approximating discrete things with high number of terms with continuous ones?

To motivate this question, i was trying to arrive myself at an approximation of $P(X \in [a,b])$ in the binomial distribution, with high number of trials, which i could not find a simple formula for. But i have no idea what to do. I am aware that it can be approximated by the normal distribution, which i purposely did not look at since i want to understand how i could arrive at it myself. But i just stare at the sum $\sum_{k= \lceil a \rceil}^{\lfloor b\rfloor} \binom nk p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ without any idea what to do...

Comment: Per my deleted answer and the ensuing conversation on it, I'll add as a comment here: the OP would prefer an answer that does not make use of pre-existing knowledge of the normal distribution.

Comment: You could probably be guided by usage requirements. What range of parameters do you want it to work for? Convergence properties, asymptotic behavior, can you work out some method which will give you samples of the discrete version from the continuous one, should it only work in some simplified subspace of the domain, or perhaps the discrete version lies in a subspace and the continuous one needs to be in a higher dimension space, ... Make anszatses with some basis functions you know... Visualize the relation you want to model with some tool you have...

Comment: Become the formula, dream it, ask yourself how would I look as a continuous function ;)

Comment: Ask yourself if it occurs in nature, and if so, what is similar to it, and how is that modeled. Maybe you can get away with tweaking some other model...